# Is there any way to variable call a PHP operator?

Tags: php, lambda

Is there a nicer way to write this (preferably without eval!)?

```
function something($value, $operator) {
  switch ($operator) {
    case '=':
      return $this->arg == $value;
    case '<':
      return $this->arg < $value;
    case '>':
      return $this->arg > $value;
// etc.
  }
}
```

It's basicaly `$operator($this->arg, $value)` except you can't do that in PHP.

Comment: How did you end up in such a weird part of the logic world? :)

Comment: I plead the Fifth. :P

Comment: I don't think so - I've leave it as it is, to be honest. If it were much longer, I might consider using `eval`, since the values are fixed and the parameters are well filtered, but it's fine as is with just three operators.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with doing it this way, I'd recommend using ircmaxell's https://gist.github.com/ircmaxell/1232629 calculator, but it basically uses the same approach to actual evaluation of the operators though he uses if/elseif/else whereas a switch is probably cleaner and easier to read

Comment: Well there's more as the etc indicates but indeed this might be the cleanest. I was mostly curious whether 5.4/5.5 introduced some new construct that'd enable for simpler but if not then that's that.

Comment: A method for each operator can be ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness -- to not leave a question unanswered: there's no way in PHP up to 5.6 to do this.